# datatables inline edit with file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

i have an inline datatable edit and i can't manage to make it work with an image upload. I don't know how to pass the image to php via ajax. I tryed diferent ways but it seems i can't or don't know how to pass the file to php. Here is my ajax code. jqInputs[2] it's file input.

```
function addRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
            var jqInputss = $(':selected', nRow);

            var path=jqInputs[2].value;
            var file = path.match(/\\([^\\]+)$/)[1];

            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(file, nRow, 2, false);
           oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a> <a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>', nRow, 4, false);
            var id = getUrlParameter('id');
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'app/producatori_add.php?id=' + id,
                data: {
                    id: jqInputs[0].value,
                    nume: jqInputs[1].value,
                    logo: file,

                },
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data)
                {

                    $("#content").html(data);

                }
            });
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }
```

Comment: You cant do fileupload with ajax this way, and certainly not as a param.  You must do this separately, try google one of the many, many tutorials on the net, google for 'ajax upload iframe or 'ajax upload filereader or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work if anyone else have this issue with inline datatable upload. I used FormData() and i sent the img to php

```
function addRow(oTable, nRow) {

            var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
            var jqInputss = $(':selected', nRow);


             var formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('name', jqInputs[1].value);
            formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 


            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false); 

           oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a> <a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>', nRow, 4, false);

             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'app/producatori_add.php',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,             

                success: function(data)
                {

                    $("#content").html(data);

                }
            });
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }
```